# Jquery button click event was not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to validate form using jquery but button click event not firing in IE .

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnResubmit2').click(function () {
        alert('btnResubmit2 Here'); 
    });
});
</script>

HTML code
 <asp:Button ID="btnResubmit2" runat="server" Text="Resubmit" onclick="btnResubmit2_Click"/>
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: In my humble understanding, you are creating two click event listeners, one with inline javascript (which will never work since there is no invoking) and another with jQuery.

Comment: onclick value is never going to fire if you don't invoke the function. It's likely throwing an error ...check your console

Comment: Don't forget that ASP.Net Webforms also changes the ID attribute of a `runat="server"` element at runtime. You may need to use `$('#<%= btnResubmit2.ClientID %>')` to select it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

**JS**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnResubmit2').click(function () {
        alert('btnResubmit2 Here'); 
    });
});
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <asp:Button id="btnResubmit2" runat="server" Text="Resubmit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the onclick attribute.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnResubmit2" runat="server" Text="Resubmit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. 
I was using Asp.net button and it was worked after done some changes like as below. I really appreciate your immediate reply.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
         $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {             
             alert('btnResubmit2 Here');
         });           
     });
```